# Command shows up under 'which' but system can't find it

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

I have Ubuntu installed on one partition of my computer and I'm trying to install Arch Linux on a second partition.  I'm having trouble with the bootable USB, so I'm trying to just install it after booting Ubuntu and I add the binary path to $PATH and the pacstrap command I need shows up when I use the which command, but it doesn't work when I try to run it.  I would just use ./pacstrap, but the it needs to be able to find other binaries that are in the same directory.

Is there a reason that the environment would be able to find a binary with 'which' but not when I execute it?

```
john@TheBrain:/storage/part4/Software/root.x86_64/bin$ export PATH
john@TheBrain:/storage/part4/Software/root.x86_64/bin$ sudo pacstrap /mnt base base-devel
sudo: pacstrap: command not found
john@TheBrain:/storage/part4/Software/root.x86_64/bin$ which pacstrap
/storage/part4/Software/root.x86_64/bin/pacstrap
john@TheBrain:/storage/part4/Software/root.x86_64/bin$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're using `sudo`, which resets your environment to use its own secure path. You can tell it to use your normal path like this:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH pacstrap
```

Comment: Or just: `sudo -E pacstrap`

Comment: @JohnStanford more than welcome :)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson should work but doesn't seem to...

Comment: Hmm.. You are right, and I found the explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18749090). Today's lesson. ;)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson thanks for finding the explanation :)